# Authenticating 3rd party app through FB Messenger iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, reactjs, webview

I'm building a web app that has Facebook authentication and also allows you to invite friends using Facebook. I found a very specific, annoying problem that I hope someone knows the answer to.

If I invite someone using Facebook, and they have the FB **Messenger** app on iOS, then once they click the link, the Messanger app opens a webview instead of Safari. So upon logging into my app, the server does not continue and ends up rendering a blank page.

Points to know:
- This only happens in iOS' Facebook Messenger
- For Android, the webview works fine and users can authenticate
- Since it's the webview and not Safari, I don't believe I can debug the code
- I also believe we don't have control over Messenger
- I know about using Messenger's webview menu to open in Safari, but I would like my users to have a better experience than that because it has to happen on every link click

Has anyone experienced this and overcome it? Or does anyone know of some secret url stuff I can do to force links to open in Safari? Or does anyone have a clue as to how I can go further in my research to finding a solution? Google is not helping...maybe this is a niche problem.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I found out that my issue is Facebook Messenger's webview is blocking popups. Ironically, since I'm using Facebook's authentication, you'd think they would allow it. Has anyone found out how to enable popups from FB Messenger?

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle this, I was advised that nothing can be done to the Messenger app to change the behavior, however, the fix was simple: all that needed to be done was to switch the authentication method to `Redirecting` instead of `Popup`. I'm using Firebase so it was really simple, but it's not difficult to change manually either. I was directed to the link below for Facebook's docs.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/